# Skip conflicts when rebase in Clearcase

Tags: jenkins, automation, clearcase

I want to automate **rebase**/**deliver** actions of **clearcase** using **jenkins**.But, if there is a conflict the build fails.
If there is a way by which we could skip the files which are failing and continue with the build. Later, fix the conflicted files manually.

Also, how to get the list of the conflicted files?

Comment: In any case, your Jenkins job should fail. But you want it to fail after *all* merges have been done, not after the first conflict. That is not possible however (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_merge.htm), considering a conflict at a folder level would then prevent any merge at the file level anyway.

Comment: Seconding this. If you have a merge conflict in what is likely a build or deployment job, skipping the merge would give you most-likely-invalid results anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`cleartool deliver`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm)/[`cleartool rebase`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm) or even [`cleartool merge`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_merge.htm), you only have the -abort option, which will cancel the deliver/rebase, but you don't have the possibility to "let a merge go all the way skipping the conflicts".

That is because any merge (UCM or not) will involve first merging folders, then files. If there is a conflict on folders, it needs to be resolved before continuing to the files.
And if there is conflicts on the files, the default behavior is to stop at the first conflict met.
Which mean there is no "list of the conflicted files"